# How to find the transition distribution functions of these two processes?

Tags: brownian-motion, reference-request, vasicek, transition-distribution

What are the transition  distribution (or density) functions of processes defined by

$dX_t=\mu dt +\sigma dW_t$

and

$dX_t= \theta(\mu-X_t) dt +\sigma dW_t,$

where $\theta>0$,  $\mu$ is a real number, $\sigma>0$, and $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

I know it is a solved problem, but I cannot find a reference that presents the detailed steps of the derivations. Could you please provide some good references? Or, could you please come with the derivations?

Comment: @Gordon the defintion of transition distribution is: $f(X=x,T=t_0+s|X=x_0, T=t_0)$ that is, the probability distribution function for $s$ period of times ahead, given that know the pocess is in $X=x_0$

Comment: @Gordon it is the limit of the previous function with $s$ going to infinity. But if you provide me the trasition distribution derivation for both (or at least one) process that would be already really helpfull.

Comment: @gordon the lim(theta->0) of the second one ought to look like the lim(mu->0) of the first one , shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks @dm63. I mixed $\mu$ and $\theta$ for the second one, which is now corrected.

Comment: @John please don't self delete posts once they receive an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We consider the first one, that is, $X_t = X_s + \mu (t-s) + \sigma (W_t-W_s)$, for $t>s$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
P(X_t \le y \mid X_s) &= P(X_t-\mu(t-s)-X_s \le y-\mu(t-s)-X_s \mid X_s)\\
&=P(\sigma(W_t-W_s) \le y-\mu(t-s)-X_s\mid X_s)\\
&=\Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu (t-s) -X_s}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}\right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
P(X_t \le y \mid X_s=x) &=\Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu (t-s) -x}{\sigma\sqrt{t-s}}\right).
\end{align*}
Here, $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable.  The transition density function can be obtained subsequently by taking the derivative with respect to $y$.

For the second one, note that, for $t>s$,
\begin{align*}
X_t = e^{-\theta(t-s)}X_s + \mu\left(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)} \right)+\sigma\int_s^te^{-\theta(t-v)}dW_v.
\end{align*}
Then, 
\begin{align*}
&\ P(X_t \le y \mid X_s)\\
=&\ P\left(X_t-e^{-\theta(t-s)}X_s - \mu\big(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)} \big) \le y-e^{-\theta(t-s)}X_s - \mu\big(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)} \big) \mid X_s\right)\\
=&\ P\left(\sigma\int_s^te^{-\theta(t-v)}dW_v \le y-e^{-\theta(t-s)}X_s - \mu\big(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)} \big) \mid X_s\right)\\
=&\ \Phi\left(\frac{y-e^{-\theta(t-s)}X_s - \mu\big(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)} \big)}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\theta}\big(1-e^{-2\theta(t-s)} \big)}} \right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
P(X_t \le y \mid X_s=x) &=\Phi\left(\frac{y-e^{-\theta(t-s)}x - \mu\big(1-e^{-\theta(t-s)} \big)}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\theta}\big(1-e^{-2\theta(t-s)} \big)}} \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand the whole idea, but I am not comfortable with the second and third equalities. Could you please provide a bit of details for these two equalities.

Comment: thanks I have understood. And about the third one? I understand it is about the standard brownian motion rules, but I miss a detail. Could you provide me with a little detail for the third equality?

Comment: Could you please give some little detail about the fourth equality of the second part, that is: $= \phi ()....$  @Gordon

Comment: @John: If this answers your question then please don't forget to upvote it and accept it. I just returned to this answer and was surprised to see that I am the only one finding it useful. I also noticed that only one of your five other questions has an accepted answer.