# How to find the transition distribution functions of these two processes?

Tags: brownian-motion, vasicek, transition-distribution

> This question was asked by another user, but was deleted. As it may be useful for others, I re-post it here.

What are the transition distribution (or density) functions of two processes defined by
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \theta(\mu-X_t) dt + \sigma dW_t,
\end{align*}
where $\theta>0$, $\mu$ is a real number, $\sigma >0$, and $\{W_t,\, t \ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Comment: I also didn't understand why it was deleted and actually voted to re-open it: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32390.

Comment: The density function for the first process can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion#Properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a derivation for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Solution to the SDE
$$dX_t = \theta(\mu-X_t) dt + \sigma dW_t$$
subject to the initial condition $X_0=x$ has the form
$$X_t= \mu + (x - \mu)e^{-\theta t} + \sigma\int_0^t e^{-\theta (t-s)}dW_s.\qquad$$
We need to calculate density function $p(t,x,y)$ of the conditional distribution $(X_t|X_0=x)$.

$X_t$ is normally distributed for each $t>0$. The conditional expectation is
$$E[X_t|X_0=x]=\mu + (x - \mu)e^{-\theta t}.$$
The conditional variance is 
$$Var[X_t|X_0=x] = \sigma^2E\left[(\int_0^t e^{-\theta (t-s)}dW_s)^2 \right] = \sigma^2 E\left[\int_0^t e^{-2\theta (t-s)}ds \right]$$
$$=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}(1-e^{-2\theta t}).$$
Hence, we have that
$$(X_t|X_0=x)\sim N\left(\mu + (x - \mu)e^{-\theta t},\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}(1-e^{-2\theta t})\right),$$
and, finally,
$$p(t,x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\theta t})/\theta}}\exp
\left[-\frac{(-y-\mu-(x - \mu)e^{-\theta t})^2}{\sigma^2(1-e^{-2\theta t})/\theta}\right].$$